# Objects to bounce around the screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, pong

I would like to make the 5 'burger' objects bounce around the screen so they are harder to shoot as is the aim of my game. But, so far they are only lining up at the top of the stage so it's way too easy to play. Would I need to create 5 separate objects with 5 separate instance names etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
var firing:Boolean = false;
var bullet:Bullet1 = new Bullet1();


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);


function keydown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
switch(event.keyCode) {
    case Keyboard.LEFT :
    ball.x -= 10;
    break;

    case Keyboard.SPACE :
    if (!firing) {
    fire();
    }
    break;

    case Keyboard.RIGHT :
    ball.x += 10;
    break;

    case Keyboard.UP :
    ball.y -= 10;
    break;

    case Keyboard.DOWN :
    ball.y += 10;
    break;

    default :
    break;
}
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);




function fire() {
addChild(bullet);
firing = true;
bullet.x = ball.x;
bullet.y = ball.y - 60
;
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movestuff);
function movestuff(event:Event):void {
if (firing) {
    bullet.y -= 20;
    if (bullet.y < 0) {
        firing = false;
        removeChild(bullet);

}
    }
}

var numBurger:Number = 5;
var array:Array = new Array();
for (var i:uint = 0; i<numBurger; i++) {
var burger:Burger = new Burger();
array.push(burger);
addChild(burger);
burger.x = 100 + 100*i;
burger.y = 50;


}
 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);
function checkCollision(event:Event)
{
for (var i:uint=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
 if (array[i].hitTestObject(bullet))

 {

 removeChild(array[i]);
  array.splice(i,1);
 return;
}
}


 }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, you are asking for someone to code the whole thing for you. I'm not going to do that, but I can point you to a sample project which does: http://www.freeactionscript.com/tag/bouncing-ball/

Comment: didn't realise it was such big a job. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, the example uses 'realistic' physics so that project might be overkill for you, but you might find some usefull code nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not have to create each movie clip separately if you use a loop to create randomized x and y locations for each burger. You can also use Math.random() to give a random speed and direction to each burger. In the code below these values are held in "direction_ary" array. This code creates five MovieClips of the "Burger"class, and places them at random points on the screen. The code also creates random speeds and directions for each MovieClip:

```
import flash.events.Event;

function find_random(max,min){
    return Math.round(min+(max-min)*Math.random());
}

var ary:Array = [];
var direction_ary:Array = [];
for(var i:uint=0;i<5;i++){
    ary[i]=new Burger();
    ary[i].name="burger"+(i);
    ary[i].x=find_random(stage.stageWidth-ary[i].width,ary[i].width);
    ary[i].y=find_random(stage.stageHeight-ary[i].height,ary[i].height);
    addChild(ary[i]);
    direction_ary[i]=[find_random(5,-5),find_random(5,-5)];
    for(var e:uint=0;e<100;e++){
        if(direction_ary[i][0]==0||direction_ary[i][1]==0){
            direction_ary[i]=[find_random(5,-5),find_random(5,-5)];
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update_burgers);
function update_burgers(e:Event){

    for(var i:uint=0;i<5;i++){
        if (ary[i].x>stage.stageWidth||ary[i].x<0){
            direction_ary[i][0]*=-1;
        }
        if (ary[i].y>stage.stageHeight||ary[i].y<0){
            direction_ary[i][1]*=-1;
        }
        ary[i].x+=direction_ary[i][0];
        ary[i].y+=direction_ary[i][1];
    }



}
```

The code is fairly self explanatory. Good luck with your project.

Cheers,
Drake Swartzy